# what is the easiest way to a convert a c++ struct to c#?

Tags: c#, c++, pinvoke

this is just an example

**I have a c++ struct like this:**

```
typedef struct _cdm_status {
    BYTE error_cd;
    BYTE sensor[9];  
} SDMSTATUS, *LPSDMSTATUS;
```

what would be the c# equivalent?

and how can I use it in this example?

```
[DllImport("MFSSDM.dll")]
public static extern bool MFSCommSDM_Status(LPSDMSTATUS lpStatus);
```

Comment: Is this for a p/invoke?

Comment: How is this used in the C++? Equivalent *exactly*? Equivalent in intent? Equivalent in "When in Rome" terms?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you are trying wanting to convert the struct so that you can pass it to a native function using p/invoke. I would do that like so:

```
public struct SDMSTATUS 
{
    public byte error_cd;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=9)]
    public byte sensor[];  
}
```

Then to declare the function you must make sure that a pointer to the struct is passed. So declare the p/invoke like this:

```
[DllImport("MFSSDM.dll", CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern bool MFSCommSDM_Status(ref SDMSTATUS Status);
```

I've assumed that the calling convention is `cdecl`, but you need to substitute the true value.

Comment: i receive this error: A call to PInvoke function 'PruebaSDM!PruebaSDM.SDM::MFSCommSDM_Status' has unbalanced the stack. This is likely because the managed PInvoke signature does not match the unmanaged target signature. Check that the calling convention and parameters of the PInvoke signature match the target unmanaged signature.

Comment: That will be calling convention mismatch. I don't know what the calling convention is because you did not show the native function declaration.

Comment: this one David? MFSCOMMSDMDLL_API BOOL __stdcall MFSCommSDM_Status(LPSDMSTATUS lpStatus);

Comment: It's right there. The calling convention is CallingConvention.StdCall

Comment: thanks david, as you see I'm learning how to do this... thanks for the great help TO ALL.

Answer (score 3):

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
public unsafe struct _cdm_status {
  public Byte error_cd;
  public fixed Byte sensor[9];  
}
```

Comment: Again, some discussion of the consequences and downsides of fixed, unsafe etc. would be useful. In fact the complete absence of text is disappointing in an answer. What's more, why select `Pack=1`? Really, it's not enough just to dump code.

Comment: Sorry for rushed answer; the reasons of "Pack = 1" and "fixed" are
when working with single bytes (field "errorCode") it's safer to align data by bytes (Pack = 1);
when working with unsafe data chunks (such as array - sensor[9]) it's reasonable to fix them in memory 
(in case there's unsafe pointer to that chunk). In many cases "Pack" and "fixed" are redundant, but 
possible errors are hard to find.

Comment: No, it's not safer to pack. It's safest to make both sides of the interface the same. In this instance the native struct does not appear to be packed and so the managed equivalent should not be either.

Comment: Your are right, the exhaustive test is sizeof() which should return the same value for
managed and unmanaged structure realization. The initial structure alignment is not specified, so
I've based on fact that "error_cd" declared as byte (not int), and "sensor" is of size 9 (not 12).

Answer (score 2):

```
public class _cdm_status
{
    public byte error_cd;
    public byte[] sensor = new byte[9];
}
```

C# doesn't have typedefs, so instead of referring to the type as "SDMSTATUS", you would just use the actual type name "_cdm_status".

Comment: Note: if your goal is interop, then see Dmitry's answer.

Comment: But that isn't even correct (`Pack=1`) and what's more needlessly uses `unsafe` and `fixed`. The best interop would use `MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValArray, SizeConst=9)`.

Comment: thank you Dave and how can I use it in this example: [DllImport("MFSSDM.dll")] public static extern bool MFSCommSDM_Status(LPSDMSTATUS lpStatus);

Comment: For interop, it's an entirely different story. See David Heffernan's comment.  My conversion is strictly a C# equivalent, not one intended for interop purposes.